# Удалить минусовые дубликаты элементов массива

Tags: массивы, ruby

Появился такой вопрос: как удалить из массива минусовые дубликаты чисел самым коротким способом в `ruby`.

К примеру, имеем массив `[1, 2, 5, -5, -6]`

Тут -5 является дубликатом минусовым дубликатом 5. На этом же примере, получаем `[1, 2, 5, -6]`

Comment: Приведите пример того, что вы уже попробовали сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью итератора `.each_with_object`:

```
a = [1, 2, 5, -5, -6]
a - a.each_with_object([ ]) { |n, b| b << -n if n > 0 }
# => [1, 2, 5, -6]
```

C помощью методов `.select` и `.map`:

```
a = [1, 2, 5, -5, -6]
p a - a.select{ |i| i > 0 }.map{ |i| -i }
# => [1, 2, 5, -6]
```

С помощью методов `.reject` и `.include`:

```
a = [1, 2, 5, -5, -6]
a.reject { |e| e < 0 && a.include?(e.abs) }
# => [1, 2, 5, -6]
```